# django admin LeafletGeoAdmin inlines

Tags: django, django-admin, leaflet

I want to add the possiblity to add more than one image on admin but i have difficulty because i use LeafletGeo.

I have make change in `models.py`

```
   class Logement(models.Model):
    titre = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    grandeur = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, choices=GRANDEUR)
    chauffe = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    eclaire = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    stationnement = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, choices=STATIONNEMENT)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date publication',default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    geom = PointField()

    class ImageLogement(models.Model):
        Logement     = models.ForeignKey('Logement', related_name="Logement")
        priorite = models.FloatField()
        picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/', default = 'photos/Aucune/no-img.jpg')
        description = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
```

the problem are in admin.py i lost LeafletGeoAdmin maps when  i want to add the two last class you can see here.

```
class LogementAdmin(LeafletGeoAdmin):
    list_display = ('titre', 'grandeur','chauffe','eclaire','stationnement')
    list_filter =('grandeur',)

class ImageLogementAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ImageLogement

class LogementAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Logement
    inlines = [ImageLogementAdmin,]

admin.site.register(Logement, LogementAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve my problem i remove

```
class LogementAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Logement
    inlines = [ImageLogementAdmin,]
```

And i add    `inlines = [ImageLogementAdmin,]` to `class LogementAdmin(LeafletGeoAdmin):`